# Select date and time automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a custom date/ time selector. That looks like this:

```
<select name="date_d">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="date_m">
    <option value="1">januari</option>
    <option value="2">februari</option>
    <option value="3">maart</option>
    <option value="4">april</option>
    <option value="5">mei</option>
    <option value="6">juni</option>
    <option value="7">juli</option>
    <option value="8">augustus</option>
    <option value="9">september</option>
    <option value="10">oktober</option>
    <option value="11">november</option>
    <option value="12">december</option>
</select>
<select name="date_y">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>

<select name="time_h">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select name="time_m">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="37">37</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="39">39</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="41">41</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="49">49</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="51">51</option>
    <option value="52">52</option>
    <option value="53">53</option>
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="57">57</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
<select name="time_s">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="37">37</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="39">39</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="41">41</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="49">49</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="51">51</option>
    <option value="52">52</option>
    <option value="53">53</option>
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="57">57</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
```

How can I accomplish that jQuery/ Javascript selects the current date and time automatically?

Comment: what do you mean automatically select?on what instance?

Comment: you want to select these dropdown based on current date time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new `Date` object which return current time and date and get individual parameter of date.

`Date` object return `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` without leading `0` so make sure to add it because values set in select are leading with zero and `month` start with `0` so current month required `+ 1`.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
$('[name=date_d]').val(currentDate.getDate());
$('[name=date_m]').val(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
$('[name=date_y]').val(currentDate.getFullYear());
$('[name=time_h]').val(currentDate.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + currentDate.getHours() : currentDate.getHours());
$('[name=time_m]').val(currentDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + currentDate.getMinutes() : currentDate.getMinutes());
$('[name=time_s]').val(currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="date_d">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="date_m">
  <option value="1">january</option>
  <option value="2">february</option>
  <option value="3">march</option>
  <option value="4">april</option>
  <option value="5">may</option>
  <option value="6">june</option>
  <option value="7">july</option>
  <option value="8">august</option>
  <option value="9">september</option>
  <option value="10">october</option>
  <option value="11">november</option>
  <option value="12">december</option>
</select>
<select name="date_y">
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>

<select name="time_h">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select name="time_m">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
<select name="time_s">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have 1 small mistake in your code, month should be + 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example with your code.
notice the only thing I changed was the select "name" I changed to "id" but you can use name as well if you really want or just add same name.

I used jQuery for easy access

```js
$(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  $("#date_d").val(currentDate.getDate());
  $("#date_m").val(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  $("#date_y").val(currentDate.getFullYear());
  $("#time_h").val(currentDate.getHours());
  $("#time_m").val(("0" + currentDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2));
  $("#time_s").val(currentDate.getSeconds());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="date_d">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select id="date_m">
  <option value="1">januari</option>
  <option value="2">februari</option>
  <option value="3">maart</option>
  <option value="4">april</option>
  <option value="5">mei</option>
  <option value="6">juni</option>
  <option value="7">juli</option>
  <option value="8">augustus</option>
  <option value="9">september</option>
  <option value="10">oktober</option>
  <option value="11">november</option>
  <option value="12">december</option>
</select>
<select id="date_y">
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>

<select id="time_h">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<select id="time_m">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
<select id="time_s">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
  <option value="33">33</option>
  <option value="34">34</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="38">38</option>
  <option value="39">39</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="41">41</option>
  <option value="42">42</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="44">44</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="46">46</option>
  <option value="47">47</option>
  <option value="48">48</option>
  <option value="49">49</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="51">51</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="53">53</option>
  <option value="54">54</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="56">56</option>
  <option value="57">57</option>
  <option value="58">58</option>
  <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for one feild , you can do it for the rest using the methods associated with the `Date` object.

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lnnskdx/)**

**CODE**:

```
$(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    $('#year').val(date.getFullYear());    
});
```

**[REFER HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm)** to know more about the date object.